# PHP always return [object Object] after an Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Have a form on a web page that is processed before to be sended to a PHP script that handle datas with :

```
$requestData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Datas are sended as JSON Object named "data":

```
[
    {
        "label": "Some label",
        "value": "Some value"
    },
    {
        "label": "Some label",
        "value": "Some value"
    },
    ...
]
```

Ajax call is make as follow :

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/App/Reserver/Ajax/ajaxcall.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data,statut){
                console.log("Données : " + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
```

When i inspect post parameters in a web browser console, have always :

```
[object Object]
...
```

And the response is NULL using :

```
$requestData = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($requestData);
```

Even if use :

```
$requestData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump($requestData);
```

I'm missing something but don't know what... Not sure of my ajax call, nor my ajax call params.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what are you even trying to do ,your code doesn't make sense

Comment: Can you show code of `ajaxcall.php`?

Comment: rather than `JSON.stringify` try `JSON.parse` - the data sent by PHP is JSON

Comment: `console.log("Données : ", data);` it should be already as an object, no need to parse data

so you send `data` as string ? What do you mean by `json object` ?

Comment: The code of ajaxcall.php should just take datas and send an email... Datas in the JSON are just contents of the future mail (i.e label : value, label : value)

Answer (score 0):

if

```
 data =[
    {
        "label": "Some label",
        "value": "Some value"
    },
    {
        "label": "Some label",
        "value": "Some value"
    },
    ...
]
```

from data:data; from your ajax sintax then

change `data:{data:data}`

and in the php use the `$_POST` variable to get the data value:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($data);
```

in the success you do:

```
success: function(data,statut){
                console.log("Données : " +data);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

$requestData = file_get_contents("php://input", NULL, NULL);
var_dump($requestData);